# ant giving classpath errors while buiding a jar that uses netscape.javascript.JSObject

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to call a javascript from an applet. I need to use netscape.javascript.JSObject for this. So i need plugin.jar from jre/libs to be referenced.

I am using ant for building. I need to cross-compile this jar to 1.5 
So while building, if I add path to jar in bootclasspath, ant build gives error:

Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

How should i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have JAVA_HOME environment variable set to point to where you have Java SDK installed.  You need to have JAVA_HOME/bin in your PATH.  You can tell if you do when you open a command shell and type "java -version".  You should see that the version of JDK you've installed is displayed.

I wouldn't recommend adding that JAR to jre/lib.  Better to add it only to the projects you need.  If Ant needs it, be sure to add it to the Ant /lib directory before you run Ant.